# simple complex variable algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do you get from this 
$$ (1+\cos(-a)+i \sin(-a))\over(2+\cos(-a)+i\sin(-a)+\cos(a)+i \sin(a)) $$
to this
$$(1+\cos(a)-i \sin(a))\over(2+2 \cos(a))$$

should i times $ (1-\cos(-a)-i\sin(-a))\over(1-\cos(-a)-i\sin(-a))$ to it?
It seems long and massey. Is there another easy way to do it. I cant see it.
Thanks you

Comment: You can try using $cis(\theta)$ notation or $e^{i\theta}$ notation

Comment: Yah Phani i got that from $e^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 7):

No, this is easier than that. Use $\sin(-a)=-\sin(a)$ and $\cos(-a)=\cos(a)$ and you get the desired fraction.

Comment: damn i see it now Thanks alot RobJohn